# Is canvas element in html5 hardware accelerated?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas

I'm pretty new to web development, in fact I'm thinking of diving into html and js for game developing.

So, before doing anything, I need to know whether or not the "canvas" element in html5 is hardware accelerated. If it's not, then I would need to use something like webgl? I don't know if it matters, but the browser I'm using is firefox(maybe it varies between browsers)

It might seem stupid, but it's an important question, specially since in games you have a bunch of 2d sprites being drawed all around.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes HTML5 Canvas is hardware accelerated but it require a Hardware Accelerated Browser. If you use chrome you can check this out by going to `chrome://gpu/`

Here is an example on how it looks:

[image]

A few articles on the same:

1. [chromium.org](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/02/gpu-accelerating-2d-canvas-and-enabling.html)
2. [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh562071.aspx)

Comment: then html is not a very good choice for game devs. I mean, if a user opens the game in a non hardwadre accelerated browser, it will be a lot slower. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I don't know that's true any more: most browsers, and certainly non-niche browsers, now utilise hardware acceleration.

Comment: We have encountered some issues where chrome will not run with hardware acceleration on certain mac machines even if its the latest browser.

Comment: Is SVG hardware accelerated? Would SVG be better than Canvas for Game Devs?