# Is 2d context considered as "webgl coding"

Tags: webgl, openlayers-3

When i am writing code as below:

```
var x = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = x.getContext("2d");
--------
--------
```

and when i am writing coding as below:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
--------
--------
```

a) Out of the above two - will both run in GPU ??

b) Is both considered as Webgl coding ??

Comment: These two code will most likely be gpu accelerated (altough the first one may be cpu rendered on older browsers). Only the second is webgl, and it exposes a different set of functions than the first one.

Comment: I have a code written in "2d" and i want it to run in "experimental-webgl". How can i use/convert 2d code to webgl ... , since i want to run my code in GPU.

Comment: The 2d and webgl contexts have very different APIs (and a different purpose), so there is no easy way to translate the code. BUT, 2d canvas is gpu accelerated by default on modern browser. Check this one out: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815646/is-canvas-element-in-html5-hardware-accelerated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815646/is-canvas-element-in-html5-hardware-accelerated)

Comment: Thanks Francois for your quick responses! I executed chrome://gpu/ on my browser and found: "Canvas: Hardware accelerated", which means that my 2d context code will also run in GPU, right ? (No need for webgl context)

Comment: You can port 2d canvas to the webgl texture . Nice way for combine to diff teh.

Answer (score 0):

Whether either "2d" or "webgl" are GPU accelerated is up to the browser and the OS.

For example [you can run Chrome using osmesa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040370/how-do-i-enable-webgl-in-headless-chrome-in-ubuntu) and it will be entirely software rendered.

In general WebGL contexts are almost always GPU accelerated, 2d contexts it depends. I know at one time 2d contexts under a certain size were not GPU accelerated in Chrome because for drawing small things software was generally faster than GPU accelerated. Whether that's still true I have no idea but that's kind of the point is that it's up to the browser and or the OS.

2d contexts are not "webgl" coding. [WebGL coding is writing GLSL shaders and calling all the necessary functions to supply those shaders with data](http://webglfundamentals.org).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please let me know how can i check/verify visually if the code is running on GPU or CPU ?

Comment: You can go to `about:gpu` in chrome and check but it won't tell you if it's always using GPU acceleration, only if it can. On other words even if "about:gpu" says canvas 2d is GPU accelerated that doesn't mean chrome is always using GPU acceleration. See example above about small contexts not being accelerated (at least in the past). 
For WebGL you can also try passing `{failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat: true}` as the second argument to `getContext` in which case if it's software rendering it *might* fail. Of course it will also fail if there is no webgl so you probably need make 2 contexts.